# Check if file exist on server to read and write

Tags: c#, winforms, server, system.net, system.web

I'm trying to use `System.Web;` to read and write into text document located on server from winform desktop application. First of all need to check if file exist. Not sure why, but System.Web does not works it is added for References as System.Web

```
string siteDir = "http://www.site.info/doc.txt";

if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(siteDir)));
```

same with `System.Web.HttpContext`

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(siteDir);
```

Comment: Try `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(siteDir);`

Comment: Is this a desktop application or a web application? You have put a winforms tag in there, which suggests this is a desktop app

Comment: You need to reference assembly `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: @StanleyS Hello. No, same result, I using System.Web; maybe I need some reference to use it?

Comment: @StanleyS yes it is done. It is System.Web there, not System.Web.dll but seems like it must be same. But same result, does not works

Comment: @nikorio So you see `System.Web` under References in the Solution Explorer ?

Comment: @StanleyS yes it is there

Comment: @nikorio do you have `using System.Web` in your code ?

Comment: @StanleyS  yes, sure. both in references and in usings

Comment: Explain "does not work".  Are you getting a compile error?  An exception?  Code runs but gives a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use `WebClient.DownloadFile()` to attempt to download a file from a url like the one you are using. If a WebException is thrown and the HTTP Error is 404 File Not Found, then the file does not exist on the server (or you do not have access to it).

See: [How to catch 404 WebException for WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387904/how-to-catch-404-webexception-for-webclient-downloadfileasync) for info on how to detect a 404 error.

Unfortunately there is no `WebClient` method that will simply check to see if a file is present on the server.

Comment: Hello, thanks, so I did it this way HttpWebResponse resp = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse; if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { //404 }

Answer (score -1):

```
use System.IO.File.Exists() 

if(System.IO.File.Exists([path of file]))
{
  // do something
}
```